# css parent child loop transitions with no hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-transitions

here's my test. http://jsfiddle.net/othoap/XdJN5/

On my html5 page I've this js that successfully fires the css.

```
 <script>
$(document).click(function(){
   $("img").fadeOut('slow', function() {
       $("img").removeClass();
      });
});
</script>
```

So I don't want a css with a mouse trigger. Just a endless loop.

As you see in the JSfiddle (MAN what a great site) example. The parent animation loops fine but the child only fires once at the start. Also I don't get why z-index won't push the child behind the parent.

As always thanks for your time.

Comment: I think your Fiddle is slightly incomplete in relation to the content of your Question

Comment: sorry new at this, should I add the hole page?

Answer (score 0):

Your animation isn't infinite because you haven't set the child to infinite:

You have this:

```
-moz-animation-iteration-count: slidedown;
-webkit-animation-iteration-count: slidedown;
```

Should be this:

```
-moz-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
-webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
```

As for `z-index`, it will not push a child behind its parent.  If you want it to be behind, it shouldn't be a child.

Comment: DOH! James to the rescue. It works great.  On the z-index, bummer. I'll try to swap the relationship then. thanks again!

Comment: swapping didn't work. The nice thing about a parent/child format is the child comes along for the ride, it's registered/synced with the parent. I guess I'd need to animate the child with both transition margin-right and margin-top. I miss Flash

Comment: @OthoapProto You could make the two elements both children of the same parent.  Then simply animate the parent side to side and the one child (with lower z-index) animate up and down.

Comment: Something like this:  http://jsfiddle.net/XdJN5/2/  You'll also need to add `position` to your elements as `z-index` only works on positioned (non-static) elements.

Comment: YES that's it - THANK YOU.  Now that makes more sense to me. I updated the  JSfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/othoap/XdJN5/4/ With your way I found I didn't need and css transitions for the "POLE" Thanks again for your time and skill.